# Problema al imprimir figura de asteriscos

Tags: python, python-3.x

Mi código me imprime lo que hay en el siguiente ejemplo:

```
   *
  **
 ***
****
```

Pero yo lo que quiero es que haya un espacio en medio de cada asterisco pero aun no he podido lograrlo, lo mas lógico seria colocarle al print de la ultima linea un espacio antes del asterisco que quede asi= " *" pero al hacer eso me imprime una figura totalmente diferente (un triangulo) podrían ayudarme

```
cantidad=int(input("Digite el numero de renglones de asteriscos: "))

for b in range(cantidad+1):  
    espacios=cantidad-b   #En esta variable se almacena la cantidad de espacios que habra en cada iteracion del for
    print(" "*espacios+"*"*b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Si no te importa tener un espacio final a la derecha, puedes hacer lo que comentas, usar `"* "`. Para evitar que la figura de "deforme" solo debes tener en cuenta que para compensar los espacios entre los asteriscos debes añadir el doble al inicio (en vez de `espacios` debe ser `espacios * 2`):

```
cantidad = int(input("Digite el numero de renglones de asteriscos: "))

for b in range(cantidad + 1):  
    espacios = (cantidad - b) * 2
    print(" " * espacios + "* " * b)
```

si quieres evitar agregar el espacio final (aunque visualmente no tiene impacto) puedes usar `str.join` para añadir los espacios intermedios, por ejemplo:

```
cantidad = int(input("Digite el numero de renglones de asteriscos: "))

for b in range(cantidad + 1):  
    espacios = cantidad - b
    print(" ".join(" " * espacios + "*" * b))
```

> ```
> Digite el numero de renglones de asteriscos: 20
>
>                                       * 
>                                     * * 
>                                   * * * 
>                                 * * * * 
>                               * * * * * 
>                             * * * * * * 
>                           * * * * * * * 
>                         * * * * * * * * 
>                       * * * * * * * * * 
>                     * * * * * * * * * * 
>                   * * * * * * * * * * * 
>                 * * * * * * * * * * * * 
>               * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
>             * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
>           * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
>         * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
>       * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
>     * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
>   * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * 
> * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * *
> ```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias ya me dio así como dices,estaba muy enredado y no lograba entender la forma de hacerlo

Comment: @Andress115, podrías validar la respuesta si ha sido de ayuda.